# Double sorting in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame that needs double-sorting, part of it is as below

```
       PERMNO   mktcap      coef
13974  11711  37.5000 1.2508261
24798  13071  72.8750 0.7413084
15294  11869  75.0000 0.3820783
33114  14170 111.3750 2.3607454
24270  13004 131.2500 4.0205943
37866  14699 131.2500 1.8548012
32190  13995 135.0000 1.7028044
30078  13768 149.2500 1.3376186
28494  13530 150.0000 1.7675992
27966  13469 188.1250 1.3499105
16350  12001 210.3750 1.7627097
30870  13848 225.0000 1.7692176
29154  13581 272.2500 1.6714913
33906  14277 309.3750 2.0797843
39186  14816 322.8750 1.6204331
7638   10911 332.7500 1.0864174
9882   11201 339.0000 1.8405390
38922  14787 363.1250 0.9696966
40638  15018 376.8750 1.5077336
34302  14306 411.7500 1.4610924
8298   11017 453.1250 2.0834445
40770  15034 528.9375 2.3746428
33774  14269 531.3750 2.0195085
32322  14007 560.6250 1.7508435
45258  15560 572.0625 2.2281513
10806  11332 577.5000 1.3420006
30342  13784 593.1250 2.0868992
22026  12722 596.7500 1.2661233
12918  11535 640.0000 2.3642444
43014  15253 641.2500 0.8406199
```

I need to divide all observations into 100 groups. The procedure involves two steps: first, divide all observations into 10 groups with equal observations in terms of the value of the variable `mktcap`; second, for each group, further divided the observations within a group into 10 groups with equal observations in terms of the value of the variable `coef`. Then add a new variable indicating the group of each observation. The value of this new variable should range from p1 to p100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data provided we can try a smaller grouping and extend the logic to the full case. We start with 5 groups:

```
#How many groups
ngrps <- 5
#Average mktcap by group size
val <- sum(df1$mktcap)/ngrps
#Cumulative sum
csum <- cumsum(df1$mktcap)
#Break data up
lbl <- cut(csum, seq(0, max(csum), by=val), labels=paste0("p", 1:5))
#Combine
cbind(df1, lbl)
```

Now that we see that this works on the data. We can wrap it in a function:

```
#Create Function
part <- function(vec, size) {
  val <- sum(vec) / size
  csum <- cumsum(vec)
  lbl <- cut(csum, breaks=seq(0, max(csum), by=val), 
           labels=paste0("p", 1:size))
  return(lbl)
}
```

Using this new `part` function we can supply any vector and size, and it will break it up into the correct number of pieces. Now to create a larger dataset:

```
df2 <- df1[sample(1:nrow(df1), 1000, TRUE),]
```

Now we have a data set big enough to break into 100 groups:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df2 %>% mutate(grp1 = part(mktcap, 10)) %>%
  group_by(grp1) %>%
  mutate(grp2 = part(coef, 10)) %>%
  mutate(grp3 = paste0("p", rleid(grp1, grp2))) %>%
  select(-grp1, -grp2)
# Source: local data frame [1,000 x 5]
# Groups: grp1 [10]
# 
#      grp1 PERMNO  mktcap     coef  grp3
#    <fctr>  <int>   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
# 1      p1  14269 531.375 2.019509    p1
# 2      p1  13469 188.125 1.349911    p1
# 3      p1  14007 560.625 1.750843    p1
# 4      p1  14007 560.625 1.750843    p1
# 5      p1  13469 188.125 1.349911    p1
# 6      p1  13530 150.000 1.767599    p1
# 7      p1  14007 560.625 1.750843    p1
# 8      p1  14277 309.375 2.079784    p1
# 9      p1  14007 560.625 1.750843    p1
# 10     p1  14170 111.375 2.360745    p2
# # ... with 990 more rows
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(PERMNO = c(11711L, 13071L, 11869L, 14170L, 13004L, 
14699L, 13995L, 13768L, 13530L, 13469L, 12001L, 13848L, 13581L, 
14277L, 14816L, 10911L, 11201L, 14787L, 15018L, 14306L, 11017L, 
15034L, 14269L, 14007L, 15560L, 11332L, 13784L, 12722L, 11535L, 
15253L), mktcap = c(37.5, 72.875, 75, 111.375, 131.25, 131.25, 
135, 149.25, 150, 188.125, 210.375, 225, 272.25, 309.375, 322.875, 
332.75, 339, 363.125, 376.875, 411.75, 453.125, 528.9375, 531.375, 
560.625, 572.0625, 577.5, 593.125, 596.75, 640, 641.25), coef = c(1.2508261, 
0.7413084, 0.3820783, 2.3607454, 4.0205943, 1.8548012, 1.7028044, 
1.3376186, 1.7675992, 1.3499105, 1.7627097, 1.7692176, 1.6714913, 
2.0797843, 1.6204331, 1.0864174, 1.840539, 0.9696966, 1.5077336, 
1.4610924, 2.0834445, 2.3746428, 2.0195085, 1.7508435, 2.2281513, 
1.3420006, 2.0868992, 1.2661233, 2.3642444, 0.8406199)), .Names = c("PERMNO", 
"mktcap", "coef"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("13974", 
"24798", "15294", "33114", "24270", "37866", "32190", "30078", 
"28494", "27966", "16350", "30870", "29154", "33906", "39186", 
"7638", "9882", "38922", "40638", "34302", "8298", "40770", "33774", 
"32322", "45258", "10806", "30342", "22026", "12918", "43014"
))
```

Comment: I ran your code, but got the error message "Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite". I am not sure what this means.

Comment: You have missing values in your data

Comment: The call `sum(is.na(df1)) == 0` should be `TRUE`

Comment: how i can fix it without changing the data. frame?

Comment: You are saying that you would like to group based on the `mktcap` and `coef` values. How do you group an element when it is missing?

Comment: i solved this issue, but how can I add the grp1 and grp3 column to the original data.frame?

Comment: You can edit the select expression `select(-grp2)`. To save you can use a two-sided pipe at the beginning, `df2 %<>% mutate(.......`. Did you notice the I changed the `%>%` into `%<>%`?

Comment: It does not work, I mean, there are supposed to be 100 groups, but I only got 10 groups with your code, is there anything wrong